# How to pass parameter using laravel's Request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-request

Currently we're doing unit testing in Laravel, and I just noticed my colleague this line below (its working fine though). I look for a [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests) in Laravel about this but I can't find it. It seems all we're just focusing on getting the request input values in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests).

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// ...more code here
$request = Request::create('/users/all', 'GET');
```

I just wanna ask how to pass a parameter using the above code line? And someone can give me a documentation about that.

Comment: Just check the create method signature: function create(string $uri, string $method = 'GET', array $parameters = [], array $cookies = [], array $files = [], array $server = [], $content = null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the create function at here:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5cfe73d95419bac1ffdddc4603db7266e428b454/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L336

As you can see, you can pass parameteres as third argument:
Example:

```php
Request::create('/users/all', 'GET', ['username' => 'admin']);
```

> Note: Laravel Request extends Symfony Base Request class

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd argument to `create` is for an array of parameters. `Illuminate\Http\Request` extends `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` which defines the `create` method:

```
public static function create(string $uri, string $method = 'GET', array $parameters = [], array $cookies = [], array $files = [], array $server = [], $content = null)
```